# How to ensure that file is created by me?

Tags: java, digital-signature

Sometimes my Java program needs to send a .dll or .so file from client computer to remote machine. Is there a possibility to ensure that this .dll (.so) file is really created by me and not by some hacker? Firstly, I thought that digital signature (java.security package) would be my first choice, but I cannot verify signature in the remote machine, because Java may not be available there. Are there any other choices?

Comment: If you don't have Java, why are you asking for Java solution?

Comment: Because my client program is written in Java, I send these files with Java and basically I'm using Java. My question is how to ensure/verify with Java that some file is really created by me.

Comment: Java is not the only language to be able to verify digital signatures. But if your client is available to hackers, hackers will be able to extract your key from the client anyway.

Comment: Can i verify this file (which is about to send to remote machine) in client computer or it would be unsafe to do that? My job is to send a valid and safe file, but how it would be used in the remote machine - I don't know. Maybe there are some other options than digital signature, which let me ensure that this file is created by me?

Comment: @polis Your question is entirely unclear. Are you responsible for the sending machine, the receiving machine or both? Who is the user of the program on the sending machine? Who is user of the receiving machine? What kind of attackers are you trying to protect this from? Why are you trying to secure it against such attackers (due to architecture such as machines are reachable through internet)?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is knowing as [non repudiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation). That is:

> - A service that provides proof of the integrity (nobody has modified your file) and origin of data (you are the genuine creator of the
>     file).
> - An authentication that can be asserted to be genuine with high assurance.

It's not about Java or C# or the language itself, it's a concept that doesn't depends on the programming language you are using. 
Every language has it's own classes, libraries, mecanisms... for dealing with that, some in a better or easier way than others.

Specifically in Java, you can start taking a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html). The steps you need:

- Generate a pair of keys (only done once).
- Sign every document you create on client side (that ensures nobody can change it, nobody can take it's ownership and nobody can refuse the ownership of the file).
- Send the document and it's signature.
- On server side, verify the validity of the signature against the provided document.

If you only want to check if the file hasn't been modified you can use a simple [digest mecanism](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33860/how-does-hashing-work) without signing, just creating a hash (don't need to create certificates, validate signature...) and verify later will work, BUT be aware that with only hash, you can't check who is the author of the file, only that the file hasn't been modified since it's hash creation.